# PDO PHP Update Script not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've searched on stackoverflow and other sources but I cant seem to find the issue that is preventing my PHP script from working.

Look at the `echo_sql`. It produces a healthy update statement which when run updates the database with no problem. Here is a sample:

```
update waste set waste_name=1 where id =82;
```

However, when the script is run, it does not apply changes to the database. Here is the script:

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    try {

        $waste_id = $_POST['waste_id'];
        $sql = new db;
        $sql->beginTransaction();

        $waste_name = $_POST['waste_name'];

        $sql->query("update waste set waste_name=:waste_name where id =:waste_id;");

        $echo_sql = "update waste set waste_name=$waste_name where id =$waste_id;";
        echo $echo_sql;

        $sql->bind(':waste_name', $waste_name);

        $sql->execute();

        $sql->endTransaction();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $sql->rollBack();
        echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Additional details:

```
errorCode() = 00000
```

DB Class:

```
class db
{

    private $stmt;
    private $dbc;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $u = "root";
        $p = "";
        try {
            $this->dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=wimsdb', $u, $p);
            $this->dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = NULL)
    {
        $this->stmt->bindParam($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function beginTransaction()
    {
        return $this->dbc->beginTransaction();
    }

    public function rollBack()
    {
        return $this->dbc->rollBack();
    }

    public function endTransaction()
    {
        return $this->dbc->commit();
    }

    public function cancelTransaction()
    {
        return $this->dbc->rollBack();
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            return $this->stmt->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->errorInfo;
        }
    }

    public function errorCode()
    {
        return $this->stmt->errorCode();
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbc->prepare($query);
    }
}
```

Please offer your suggestions on how this could be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `:waste_id` too:

```
    $waste_id = $_POST['waste_id'];
    $sql = new db;
    $sql->beginTransaction();

    $waste_name = $_POST['waste_name'];

    $sql->query("update waste set waste_name=:waste_name where id =:waste_id;");


    $sql->bind(':waste_name', $waste_name);
    $sql->bind(':waste_id', $waste_id);
```

Any time you have an issue like this your error checking should return a meaningful message letting you know where the error is and likely *what* the error is. You should be able to check your error logs for details and/or output them to your screen during testing.

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir. I am astounded by the level of my blunder. Script confirmed working.

Answer (score 0):

Add waste_id.  To avoid missing parameters, I like putting the parameteers into the execute method.  The bind method could be defined anywhere in the code so I had to look through your code and make sure waste_id binding wasn't defined somewhere else.  When it's in the execute method, you can quickly see all parameters being defined there...it's also a tad more concise...but both have their uses.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

try {

    $waste_id = $_POST['waste_id'];
    $sql = new db;
    $sql->beginTransaction();

    $waste_name = $_POST['waste_name'];

    $sql->query("update waste set waste_name=:waste_name where id =:waste_id;");

    $echo_sql = "update waste set waste_name=$waste_name where id =$waste_id;";
    echo $echo_sql;

    //just because I like this syntax for being concise and clear :)
    $sql->execute(array(
        'waste_id'   => $waste_id,
        'waste_name' => $waste_name
    ));

    $sql->endTransaction();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $sql->rollBack();
    echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard, yeah, I have a bad habit of posting quick and then editing a million times :-P